# I am trying to make a real-time auto-correct sort of add-on for Google Docs using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to make a real-time auto-correct sort of add-on for Google Docs using Google Apps Script. I have written a lot of code, yet cannot figure out why the fixWords function does not work. Whenever I type a word, it does not auto-correct. This is my code:

```
function fixWords() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  //The start of replacing...
  body.replaceText("accomodate","accommodate");
  body.replaceText("accomodation","accommodation");
  body.replaceText("acheive","achieve");
  body.replaceText("accross","across");
  body.replaceText("agressive","aggressive");
  body.replaceText("agression","aggression");
  body.replaceText("apparantly","apparently");
  body.replaceText("appearence","appearance");
  body.replaceText("arguement","argument");
  body.replaceText("assasination","assassination");
  body.replaceText("basicly","basically");
}
```

Any suggestions? I am a newbie to Apps Script but have programming for three years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something in Docs for automatic substitution.  Under the tools, menu, click preferences.  You can also add a personal dictionary.

If you could add a personal dictionary from code, that would probably work, but I don't see a way to do that.

There is no trigger or way to monitor a Google doc for every keystroke made.  See the documentation:

[Trigger Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Something would need to trigger your function to run on every keystroke.  In a spreadsheet, there *is* an `onEdit()` simple trigger that monitors every change to a cell.  But there is nothing like that for Google Docs.

The only event type available to a Google Doc is `open`.

Comment: Yes, an add-on that predicts the winning lottery number.  ;)  If I had an awesome idea, I probably would keep it to myself, or at least not post it publicly.