# Apps script tigger on autocorrect

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to make it so you can see when the user uses autocorrect to change a word? For example:

```
void onEdit() {
    if (*Function*)
        Logger.log(*word autocorrected*);
}
```

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315225/i-am-trying-to-make-a-real-time-auto-correct-sort-of-add-on-for-google-docs-usin) if it can help you.